# Remove line break in tex file

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting

**Remark:** I'm working with `.tex` (TeX) file.

In TeX code, line break does not affect the output. To produce a new paragraph we have to use the `\par` command.

Some TeX editors interpret a blank line as `\par`. So the following code

```
line one here
continues here and so on

New paragraph here
```

produces the output

> line one here continues here and so on
>
> New paragraph here

Since some editors can wrap long lines automatically I like to write my codes with less RETURN as possible. This is better when we want to take care of line numbers.

See the screen-shot:

[image]

I'd like to remove the end of lines but keep the blank lines **even if they contain only white spaces**. After the process I'd like my code like this:

[image]

Note that the new code contains only 3 lines.

I tried using `tr` but no success.

**Edit:** after testing the code suggested by @lcd047, I noticed that some problems appear when the line `n` contains `%` (`%` is used to comment in TeX and everything after it in the line is ignored).

So, I guess that I should add the **request**: if line `n` contains `%` don't glue `n` with `n-1` neither don't glue `n+1` with `n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
awk '!NF || /%/ {printf "%s", (NR > 1 ? "\n" : "") $0; sep = "\n"; next}
     {printf "%s", sep $0; sep = " "}
     END {if (NR) print ""}' < file.in > file.out
```

Comment: Thanks. Please, I edited the request. Is it possible to adapt your code?

Comment: @Sigur, see edit.

Comment: Nice! It works. Does make sense to use `|| /%/ || /\/ ` to protect also lines starting with back slash? Many lines on preamble of `tex` files starts with `\\`  so it is natural to keep one above others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```bash
perl -lpe 'BEGIN{ $/= $\ = "\n\n" } s/^[^%]+?\K\n/ /gmo' <file_old.tex >file_new.tex
```

To also leave alone lines staring with commands:

```
perl -lpe 'BEGIN{ $/= $\ = "\n\n" } s/^\s*[^\s\\%][^%]*?\K\n/ /gmo' <file_old.tex >file_new.tex
```

Please note however that some of the people reviewing your papers will hate you with a passion for this move.

Comment: Well, usually they don't know that the editor can wrap lines automatically. I'm trying your code. How to save the result in a new file?

Comment: Some editors (e.g. Vim) can wrap lines automatically but make it hard for the user to navigate through continuation lines.  To save the result: `awk ... file.tex > newfile.tex`.

Comment: Ow, thanks. It works. But some problems appear when there are commented lines with `%` in the middle. After gluing the lines, anything after `%` is commented. I don't see a way to solve this.

Comment: Maybe, doing this: if the line `n` contains `%` anywhere, don't move the line `n+1` to the end of line `n`.

Comment: Right.  I edited my answer to address comments.

Comment: Almost. Now the lines are duplicated when glued.

Comment: Belated solution with perl.